# Primordals while trying to start a repo

Tags: javascript, web, discord, vps

Primordals error keeps going off each time I try to start https://github.com/discordboats-club/website/ on my vps so it starts then stops here is the full error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kutbd.png)

```
    Creating a pool connected to localhost:28015
fs.js:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:26
    at req_ (/root/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/root/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/graceful-fs/f                            s.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/graceful-fs/g                            raceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
```

Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish. Is the Github project your project, or something you're newly contributing to?  
What is fs.js? I'm guessing it's a JavaScript file from that project's code that you're not familiar with. Please elaborate on the context, and on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to stop the 
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined error and yes fs is a js file